# fetch both created_by_id and assign_to_id names from two tables users and tasks

Tags: mysql, database

I have two Tables 1st

**Users**

```
SELECT users.*,tasks.*
from users
join tasks on users.id=tasks.assign_to
```

[image]

2nd is
**Tasks**

```
SELECT users.*,tasks.*
from users
join tasks on users.id=tasks.created_by
where tasks.created_by=5
```

[image]

here i want to show result this result is is not correct it shows only **created_by** correct but **assign_to** not correct. 
*I need Name of both **created by** and **assign to** users in one query*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try two joins of the users table.

```
SELECT
  tasks.*,
  created_by_user.name AS created_name,
  assigned_to_user.name AS assigned_name
FROM tasks
INNER JOIN users created_by_user
  ON created_by_user.id = tasks.created_by
INNER JOIN users assigned_to_user
  ON assigned_to_user.id = tasks.assign_to
WHERE tasks.created_by = 5
```

Comment: how can i used in result table mean how can i call both same name field seperately.

Comment: You can use aliases. I added some to differentiate in the select list